# Handling Outlier Data (Insurance Prices)

Tags: regression, machine-learning, data-preprocessing

59,000 observations were conducted. Each observation is a different combination of attributes (X) of a car [age, make, model, etc] and its driver [age, years license held, at fault accident, etc] and that returns a price for insurance (y).

This histogram shows number of experiments that returned insurance quotes in the range \$200-\$400. (bin size = \$25)

[image]

It appears that after the data was captured, all quotes over \$400  have been rolled into the \$375-\$400 bin.

(Note: While there are other explanations for this distribution, for the sake of this question, please assume this assumption to be true.)

I am learning and am hoping for some advice on the following question....

Will this "rolling up" of results over \$400 skew my predictions? (for example using LinearRegression() in SKLearn). How would you normally preprocess this data to avoid skewing the result?

[Edit: adding plot with bins size=1]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The rolling up of the outliers into a lower category will certainly cause some bias, but it's impossible to know how much, without knowing what the actual quotes were. If none were much over $400 then it won't be much of a problem. If some were much higher, it could be a big problem.

Also, binning the quotes isn't a great idea as it loses information.

You should leave each price as a price and not bin at all.

If you only have the data in this format, then I would try ordinal logistic regression, instead of linear regression.

Comment: I have the price data to 2 decimal places. What would you suggest is the best way to plot the data please?

Comment: If you want just to plot the prices, I'd use a density plot and a box plot. But from your second box plot, it seems like you only have the prices when they are below $400. Without knowing more about why there are no quotes above $400, it's hard to recommend anything.